# Clarification about angularJS e2e testing using the API - element(selector, label).query(fn)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

**I have the following e2e test code in my angularJS app.**

*Please read the code and also the comments to understand my issue. Also I attached an image that shows the output of the test.*

```
it('should display the table header values', function() {

    var _mockTopicTitles = [
    {name: 'Course ID'},
    {name: 'Title/Confluence'},
    {name: 'Owner'},
    {name: 'Date Created'},
    {name: 'Reviewed Date'},
    {name: 'NCRU'},
    {name: 'Duration (Hrs)'},
    {name: 'Survey'},
    {name: 'NPS Stats'}
    ];

    var promise = element(".tab-pane:first .panel-content table thead tr th", "traversing the table thead rows").query(function(elements, done) {

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        //a. This will log in the chrome console. See the attached image.
        console.log("Elements[]", elements[i].innerText);

        //b. However, elements[i].innerText is evaluated as undefined when running the test. See the image.
        expect(elements[i].innerText).toEqual(_mockTopicTitles[i]["name"]);
    }
    done();
    });


    for (var i = 0; i < promise.length; i++) {
         //c. Why the code below isn't logged in the chrome console?
        console.log("Promise[]", promise[i].innerText);
    }

});
```

I can't attached the image directly because it needs 10 reputation. That is why I uploaded
it in the cloud. Please see this image.

https://copy.com/69qg0PiIf2KN

Obviously, the left side of the image part is the runner.html and the right side is the chrome console.

**So here are my questions.**

1. Why does elements[i].innerText is evaluated as undefined even it has value when I log it in the console? See the attached image.
2. Also, the last for loop does not display anything in the console. Can someone explain this to me?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Have no idea, maybe a bug with the framework. Hope some AngularJS expert can answer  this question.
2) it is working as designed.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianEdiomaMigraso for your answer in number 2. :) Hopefully  someone will also answer question number 1.